# Regex: match content between first and last dash

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract the content between the first and last dash (without spaces at the start and at the end).

Original text:

```
Country - Name part1 - part 2 - 1234567
```

Output should be:

```
Name part1 - part 2
```

What I have got so far is:

```
(\-[\w\s]+\-)
```

But it [outputs](https://regex101.com/r/cB0kB8/65):

```
- Name part1 -
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the below regex and get the string you want from index 1

```
-(.*)-
```

Comment: Or `-([\s\S]*)-` to include newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dash to your `[\w\s]` and it will work.

`\w` itself doesn't covers the dash.

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/uD4iI4/1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was looking for a way to "exclude" the dashes, and just return the content inside "Name part1 - part 2".

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno. Just put the dashes outside the group